# How to display 2^3 in Javascript

Tags: javascript, iphone, android, appcelerator, mathematical-expressions

I am building an app using appcelerator which needs to display a mathematical expression e.g 2^3 but with the 3 being a small number above the 2. Is there a way to express mathematical expressions in Javascript?

**Notes**

- The text is a static bit of text.
- Language in use is Javascript.
- Runs on the iPhone/Android simulator in the appcelerator framework.
- Appcelerator escapes HTML

Thanks in advance for any assistance.

Comment: I suppose the end result is it being displayed, so maybe there is a special html power code or something

Comment: What about brackets? How full-fledged should it be?

Comment: Have you tried using unicode characters?  (^3 is 00B3)

Comment: Its relatively simple, I just have a couple of labels like cm^2. Just tried adding some html tags around the text and it seems appcelerator escapes html tags.

Comment: Is it client side that shoud be represented in browser? if it is so you may use simple markup <i>x</i><sup>2</sup>

Comment: it's a pity that [MathML](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MathML) doesn't have wider cross-browser support, or I'd have recommended it. But as it is, it isn't supported by any of the mobile browsers, which rules it out for you.

Answer (score 2):

`"2"+"3".sup()` should give you the correct formatting.

You can also use `.sub()` for subscript.

Answer (score 2):

if you are concerned only about the display, you can make use of the html tags `<sub></sub>` and `<sup></sup>` which makes the text between them **sub**script and **sup**erscript.
A big plus is that the native javascript string has the functionality of returning a string wrapped into theese tags (not that it would've been very hard to implement):

```
var a = "2",
    b = "3",
    formattedEquation = a+b.sup(),
    r = Math.pow(a,b),
    htmlEquation = formattedEquation + ' = ' + r;
// let's say you use jquery for the simplicity of the example
$(myContainer).html(htmlEquation);
```

Answer (score 1):

For more elaborate mathematical typesetting, you might be able to use the [MathJax](http://www.mathjax.org/) JavaScript display engine.  It looks to be fully compatible with WebKit and seems to typeset things fine on my iOS devices.

Answer (score 0):

There are the [`<sup>` and the `<sub>` tags](http://www.whatwg.org/specs/web-apps/current-work/multipage/text-level-semantics.html#the-sub-and-sup-elements) in HTML, try this:

```
<html>x<sup>4</sup>+y<sup>1245687</sup></html>
```

If this isn't enough, take a look at [MathML](http://www.w3.org/TR/MathML/)

Comment: this works in HTML but I think the OP has a problem with Appcelerator escaping HTML tags.

Comment: My understanding of appcelerator was, you build a webapp and have additional javascript apis to the native functions of the phone. Don't you write HTML pages in appcelerator?

Comment: thats my understanding too. I was referring to the OP's comment on his original question. I think he needs to include more source code.

Comment: For things like JQueryMobile, but with Appcelerator you write it in javascript and it then compiles it and generates native iOS and Android code.

Answer (score 0):

Some good ideas which would work on platforms like JQueryMobile but unfortunately Appcelerator escapes all html (Unless your coding just for the Android).

The way to display the mathematical expressions is by defining the unicode character in the string as suggested by Pat in a comment.

E.g.

```
2\u00B3
```